# QProcess "\n\r" in git bash.exe does not work?

Tags: git, bash, qt, qprocess

I am trying to run under **QProcess** the ***bash.exe*** from **git**. I've checked if the process is running and if the file exists and confirmed these but when trying to write to process a command and after that have "**\n\r**" it doesn't do anything.

Sample code:

```
QProcess *proc = new QProcess();
proc->start("C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe");
proc->waitForStarted();
proc->write("ls\n\r");
proc->waitForBytesWritten();
proc->waitForReadyRead();
# neither proc->readAll() nor proc->readAllStandardOutput(); fetch anything
# tried even proc->readAllStandardError(); but no luck as well.
```

So it just sits there and I don't get the directory listing.
What might be the problem?

Comment: `bash` expects its commands to be terminated by a line feed only, not a line feed and a carriage return, although I don't think that would explain the lack of output here, unless it is waiting for the full command that starts with `\r` to be entered.

Comment: `\n\r` is not a line ending on any system anyone is likely to be using and is most certainly **not** the line ending for `Windows`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't understand how your code even compiles, because there is no `QProcess` constructor that accepts string as an argument.

Here is what I would read the output of `ls` command using `QProcess`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{       
    QProcess proc;
    proc.start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe", QStringList());
    if (!proc.waitForStarted()) {
        return 1;
    }
    proc.write("ls\n");
    QByteArray output;
    if (proc.waitForReadyRead()) {
        output += proc.readAll();
    }
    qDebug() << output;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, you are right, I wrote the question in a hurry. Edited it.